# How to make reference to a codebox?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am using the `clrscode3e` package to typeset pseudocode and I want to make reference to the procedures in `codebox`es to produce something like "Procedure InsertionSort". How to do that?

For example, if I want to make reference to a chapter, I can easily write:
`\label{chap:foo}` and `\nameref{chap:foo}`, then I get the chapter name.

How can I get the procedure name (defined by `\proc{}` in `codebox` environment) by just make reference to it (that is, I can just define `\label{proc:InsertionSort}` in `codebox` then use `\nameref{proc:InsertionSort}` to get the name of the procedure somewhere else)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) show a sample of what you want to link to.

Answer (score 5):

Since a procedure `\Procname` under the `codeblock` environment from [`clrscode3e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/clrscode3e) does not have a number associated with it, only `\nameref` would make sense.

The following modification to the `\Procname` macro in [`clrscode3e`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/clrscode3e/clrscode3e.sty) updates the hyperlink target as well as the "name to be referenced":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{clrscode3e,etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\robustify{\proc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Procname}[1]{%
  \global\def\saveprocname{#1}%
  \global\procnametrue%
  \let\@currentlabelname\saveprocname
  \phantomsection}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}
See \nameref{proc:insertion-sort}.

\begin{codebox}
  \Procname{$\proc{Insertion-Sort}(A)$}\label{proc:insertion-sort}
    \li \For $j \gets 2$ \To $\attrib{A}{length}$
      \li \Do
      $\id{key} \gets A[j]$
      \li \Comment Insert $A[j]$ into the sorted sequence
      $A[1 \twodots j-1]$.
      \li $i \gets j-1$
      \li \While $i > 0$ and $A[i] > \id{key}$
        \li \Do
        $A[i+1] \gets A[i]$
        \li $i \gets i-1$
        \End
      \li $A[i+1] \gets \id{key}$
    \End
\end{codebox}

\end{document}
```